# is it possible to store a character as underlined within a sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, utf-8, underline

I am trying to create a database for an android app including, in part, non-English words which require underlines and accents for proper spelling.  I set my encoding for this package to utf-8, which allowed the accented characters to store and display properly.  However, I cannot seem to get a single character underlined.  It displays an empty box for an unrecognized character.

An example of my database helper to create the sqlite is as follows:

```
cv.put(ENGLISH, "to be alive");
cv.put(NATIVE, "okch_á_a or okchaha");
cv.put(PART_OF_SPEECH, "verb");
cv.put(AUDIO, "alive");
cv.put(VIDEO, "none");
cv.put(IMAGE_DEFAULT, "none");
cv.put(IMAGE_OPTIONAL, "none");
cv.put(IMAGE_TO_USE, "none");
db.insert("words", ENGLISH, cv);
```

That
    _ a _
is the best I can come up with so far, but the a should actually be an underlined character.

I tried html tags like u and /u: 
    <u>a</u> 
since that works with string arrays, but it displays as: 
    <u>a</u> 
(the html is never interpreted).

I tried using: 
    "\u0332" 
as explained at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/332/index.htm , but that, too, is never interpreted, so it displays as: 
    a\u0332

I also tried: 
    & # 818 ; 
and: 
    & # x332 ; 
in a similar manner, with similar lack of results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your string in Html format and call .setText(Html.fromHtml(somestring)) from the textview were you want to display it.

Comment: That did it Paschal - thanks! Database Helper code now looks like:   cv.put(ENGLISH, "to be alive");
  cv.put(CHICKASAW, "okch<u>á</u>a or okchaha");
  cv.put(PART_OF_SPEECH, "verb");
  cv.put(AUDIO, "alive");
  cv.put(VIDEO, "none");
  cv.put(IMAGE_DEFAULT, "none");
  cv.put(IMAGE_OPTIONAL, "none");
  cv.put(IMAGE_TO_USE, "none");
  db.insert("words", ENGLISH, cv);
 and my setText code looks like this: nativeWrittenText.setText(Html.fromHtml(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("chickasaw"))));   and it seems to function as I had wanted.  Thanks again!